# integration by parts with product of 3 variables.

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I apply integration by parts with this expression $$\int {2r\frac{{d\theta }}{{dt}}\frac{{dr}}{{dt}}} \, + {r^2}\frac{{{d^2}\theta }}{{d{t^2}}}\,dt\,\,
$$ to get the answer = $${r^2}\frac{{d\theta }}{{dt}}
$$
There are three variables, and every time I try I can't get the answer like above, also this answer can be verified by simple differentiation so it is true.
please help. Thanks

Comment: Hint: integration by parts comes from differentiation and the product rule. Differentiate the answer.

Comment: I want to know the steps that were taken starting from the integral to get the last expression i mentioned.

Comment: I want you to differentiate the answer.

Comment: $u=r^2$ and $v=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ can you proceed?

Comment: @KurtG. using the formula $$\int {u\,dv\,\,\, = \,\,\,uv - \int {v\,du} \,}$$ it gives.
$${{r^2}\frac{{d\theta }}{{dt}} - \int {\frac{{d\theta }}{{dt}}2r\frac{{dr}}{{dt}}} }
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-!
$$what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing. Since $dv=\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\,dt$ you wrote $$\int r^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\,dt=r^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}-\int \frac{d\theta}{dt}2r\frac{dr}{dt}\,dt$$ which is equivalent to the equation you were starting with in OP.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks but how would the 2nd term cancel, because it will also have negative integral.

Comment: The term with the minus sign goes to the left hand side and gets a plus sign. This is then the equation you were supposed to show.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot, so basically I had to integrate just one term and rearrange to get the equation I wanted, but to be honest that was very tricky (for me at least, call me noob), actually I was integrating both terms and then adding them to get the answer i wanted-  I couldn't have done it without someone's help. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I hope you learned that you basically just have to know the product rule and the rest follows.

Answer (score 1):

The first term is integrated by parts as follows :
$$
\int 2r\dot{r}\dot{\theta} \mathrm{d}t = r^2\dot{\theta} - \int r^2\ddot{\theta} \mathrm{d}t
$$
And the remaining integral cancels with the second term in your original expression.